# Anonymous user login using firebase with angular and spring boot

Tags: angular, firebase, spring-boot, firebase-authentication

I am developing an Angular 10 app using spring boot as a server. I want to anonymously login users using firebase, I use this for favorite items etc and I need the user to be logged in before the first backend request. I added angularfire dependency, I sign in the user anonymously and I get the user token as follows:

```
    this.auth.signInAnonymously()
      .catch(err =>
        //log the error
      );

    this.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        const token =  user.getIdToken();

        user.getIdToken(true).then(idToken => {
          this.cookieService.set('Authorization', idToken);
        });
      }
    });
```

I added the token to the cookies because I want to use it on the backend side (and I don't want to make a filter to add it to every request as a header):

```
FirebaseToken decodedToken = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(authCookie.get().getValue());
```

My problem is that after a while the token expires and on the backend I receive the following error:

> Firebase ID token has expired. Get a fresh ID token and try again

I can't figure out if I can refresh the token from the backend. Is there any way to handle refreshing the token when it expires? (before calling the backend with an expired token)

Can you give me an idea on how to design anonymous login without much delays and without retries?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You should add code to listen to change in the ID token, as it gets automatically refreshed every hour.  Use [onIdTokenChanged](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onidtokenchanged)

```
firebase.auth().onIdTokenChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in or token was refreshed.
  }
});
```

You will need to update your cookie every time the callback triggers due to an ID token change.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I check with onIdTokenChanged but the callback isn't triggered on token expiry and I check in index db and the token isn't refreshed. Do I need to call another method to refresh token?

Comment: No, it should happen automatically as long as the user is signed in.  If that's not happening, then you might want to file an issue on GitHub with your code that reproduces the issue.